# Clone in jQuery number of times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting an item to `localStorage` with the syntax of `#id, #id+number of times div has been duplcated`. The reason for this is that I have a button that `.clone()`'s the div as many times as the user clicks it, and then saves which div was cloned and how many times to localstorage. My problem, however, is figuring out how to `.clone()` it back to the page as many times as the number value in the localstorage item was.

For instance, if the localstorage item was this: `(#one, #one-5)`, I would want div `one` to be cloned `5` times to the body.

My code thus far can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/fLJcs/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some sort of a loop with a counter. [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) will be perfectly sufficient.

```
var max = 5;
for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
    // clone here
}
```

or

```
var max = 5;
while(max--) {
    // clone here
}
```

Comment: And then `all[0]` would be the ID of the element, and `all[1]` would be the number of times it gets cloned?

Comment: Something like that. I agree with @sachleen's question, though. The localStorage item format does not make any sense to me. Why not just stringify to JSON? A format like `{"id":"one", "count": 5}` would do. You don't have to write any parsing or serialization code beyond `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I believe the reason why I used my current syntax for the storage is because I wasn't sure how to group the ID with the number, but I realize now I could've just set it to a variable: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/fLJcs/3/

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it make more sense to just have the count as the second item in the localstorage?

```
(#one, 5)
```

Anyway, you want to use a loop to iterate n times (5 in this case) and each time append the element.

Something like

```
// n is the number of times to clone (n=5 here)
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // clone your element
}
```

[Duplicate and Clone Elements Multiple Times](http://jqueryminute.com/duplicate-and-clone-elements-multiple-times/) maybe be useful, too. A little jQuery plugin to abstract this.

I don't know how you're storing this in localstorage, but you can [stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) objects and store them.

```
myobject = {
  'id': 'one',
  'count': 5
}
// Save
localStorage.setItem('myobject', JSON.stringify(myobject));
// Retrieve
var myobject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myobject'));
```

Now you can just get its attributes like `myobject.id` and `myobject.count`.

Comment: So `n` would be `all[1]`? And I suppose so, on your first point. I'm trying to figure out why I have it like it is now.

Comment: I don't know what `all[1]` is. It is however you get the 5 out of `#one-5`.

Comment: I strongly recommend using the technique I suggested in my updated answer. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Is your updated way better than this way (using your syntax suggestion): http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/fLJcs/3/

Comment: It's more understandable than the first fiddle. I think what I suggested is better (I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise, right?) but do what works for you. What I gave you works in all cases, with any kind of object. If you only need this one key-value pair, then what you have works. If you might need to do more, it would be a good idea to plan for it starting now. I'd still get rid of the `#one-5` and make it just `5`.

Comment: I made `one-5` `5`. I won't be needing the key-value at all after it sets the divs, so I think I'll keep it. I am wondering though... I have it setup so that they all get an id of `id+number of divs`. I forgot to mention in the OP that they ID's have ot be unique. So if there's 3 divs of id `one`, then I'd like there to be `#one-1`, `#one-2`, and `#one-3`. Is this even possible?

Comment: You don't really have a choice on the uniqueness of IDs. By definition, it's unique.

Comment: But `#one-2` is different from `#one-1`, therefore they're unique. What I'm asking is, can the id's have the number at the end of them appended starting from 0 up until the max limit (ex. 5)?

Comment: I dunno. Why not? Set the ID to whatever you want.

Comment: Haha, I know... but I honestly can't figure out how. If I set a variable to 0, then had it increment it x times, that should accomplish it. But I don't know if I should use for or with or .each()...

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LShYs/.

Basically, you simply add a loop:

```
for (var i=0; i< parseInt(all[1])-1; i++){
   duplicateDiv("#" + all[0]);
}
```

and extract your click event to a new method (duplicateDiv) which is now called from your click handler and the loop. Pretty straightforward.